R-square of trendline
I am analysing rabbit data, where I have calculated the average number of offspring per birthyear, using: the AVERAGE-function. This variable is a measure.
I have added this data to a line chart and I have added a trendline using 'Trend line' from the Format panel.
I know want to know the R-square, like you would get in Excel. (Add trendline and then add R-square in graph).
I would like to either show the R-square in the graph, or just in another visual such as a Card. Which measures would I need for that? Or is there anyother easy way to show the R-square?

this help? https://medium.com/@Bolaji.BI/correlation-coefficient-in-power-bi-the-easy-way-981161602583
